# How te read Object in Jade Pug?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, pug, jade4j

I have this JSON that I send to the PUG page from router.get with the name of `prices`

> [{"space2":{"actualPrice":"$ 99.990","oldPrice":"$
> 129.990","id":11098071}},{"h20":{"actualPrice":"$ 69.990","oldPrice":"$ 79.990","id":4444311}},{"space":{"actualPrice":"$ 79.990","oldPrice":"$ 99.990","id":4436762}}]

and in a pug page I want to show `actualPrice` of `space2` but I dont know how.

I tried with `prices.space2.actualPrice` and in a for cycle and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question looks like a Javascript question rather than a Pug question. The following:

```
-
  const Data = [
    {"space2":{"actualPrice":"$ 99.990","oldPrice":"$ 129.990","id":11098071}},
    {"h20":{"actualPrice":"$ 69.990","oldPrice":"$ 79.990","id":4444311}},
    {"space":{"actualPrice":"$ 79.990","oldPrice":"$ 99.990","id":4436762}}
  ]

p Only space2: 
  each d in Data 
    if d.space2 
      | #{d.space2.actualPrice}
```

will output:

> Only space2: $99.9990

---

Are you certain you want to structure your data object in this manner? You can access the details of each element of the array *only* if you know the first property key of each element. For example, it will be pretty tough to list out the `actualPrice` of every item in your array.

Depending on what your situation is, it might be more useful if your data is organized as:

```
const Data = [
  {"name": "space2", "actualPrice":"$ 99.990","oldPrice":"$ 129.990","id":11098071},
  {"name": "h20", "actualPrice":"$ 69.990","oldPrice":"$ 79.990","id":4444311},
  {"name": "space", "actualPrice":"$ 79.990","oldPrice":"$ 99.990","id":4436762}
]
```